# Asynchronous tasks in C# console application combined with Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, console-application

Let's say I have 10 tasks which should run simultaneously visualizing their progress using GUI. For simplicity let them be just counters 1 to 100. Main app should be console application. GUI controls should be generated on the fly.
Here's the code I've written:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList().ForEach(x =>
                                                    frm.Controls.Add(new Label()
                                                    {
                                                        Left = 10,
                                                        Top = 22 * x,
                                                     }));

            Thread mThread = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                frm.ShowDialog();
            });

            mThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            mThread.Start();

            Jobs();
         }

static void Jobs()
        {
            Task[] tasks = new Task[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = PayLoad(i);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        }

static async Task PayLoad(int taskNumber)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskNumber} is starting...");
            //await Task.Delay(1000);

            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskNumber} - iteration {i}    ");

                Action act = delegate () { frm.Controls[taskNumber].Text = i.ToString(); };
                frm.BeginInvoke(act);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

        }
```

The problem is the progress stops when all counters reach 1. If I comment the 2nd await the code completes but I can see it works synchronously. All the labels are filled one by one.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Make these changes; make `Jobs()` `async`: `static async Task Jobs()` and in the method use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`. In Main, call `Task.Run(Jobs);` Now your Tasks are awaited. You should see a concurrent update of the Labels on the Form and the Console.

Comment: Btw, change the invocation in `frm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => frm.Controls[taskNumber].Text = i.ToString()));`. The Form should also be *interactive*.

Comment: Btw2, you could also eliminate the Thread and call `Application.Run(frm);` right after `Task.Run(Jobs);` (the Form is not modal, in this case). You only need to add a `CancellationToken` to cancel the Tasks if the Form is closed, otherwise all Task will raise an exception. This is probably the more interesting exercise.

Comment: Btw3. Since I don't see `[STAThread]` applied to `Main`, you should add it if it's not there. You also must have `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of Main.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi ! I've made changes proposed by you in the first comment except await Task.WhenAll(tasks). Because "can't wait for void". Anyways, it works now as expected!

Comment: If you made all the changes I suggested, you wont' get `can't wait for void` in `await Task.WhenAll()`. If you want, I can post an example that includes all the *suggestions* in one piece.

Comment: Thanks, but not needed. It works without it.